# Xcode 7 with Swift 2 - AppCrashing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

today I downloaded the new Xcode Version and update my App to Swift 2 code.
But now my App is crashing on start the App on my iPad.
The error looks like this:

```
**dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x120099088 <+0>: brk    #0x3**
```

This is my only information.

Informations:
I use my iPad with iOS9 and my Deployment is iOS9 too.
I use belowed shown libaries:

```
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~> 1.5.1'
  pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~> 1.5.1'
  pod 'AFDateHelper', '~> 3.1.0'
  pod 'SwiftHUEColorPicker', '~> 0.1.5'
  pod 'UIColor_Hex_Swift', '~> 1.1'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
```

Furthermore I use this libaries for my own Framework which is implemented in my App too.

```
 pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2'
 pod 'SwiftSerializer', '~> 0.1'
```

I hope you can help me.

Best regards,
Seb

Comment: In addition to actions suggested by @moonie I would also suggest deleting Derived Data. It can be easily googled (I started to write an instruction, but it turned out to be a bit long for a comment).

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and give you feedback.

Comment: Boy, those are a lot 3rd party libs. And ActionSheetPicker comes twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Product > Clean` your project.

Or press `Cmd + Q` and relaunch Xcode.